# how do I store the links to an attachment in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I need to make a table such that the user can add attachment links to one of the fields. Is there a way to allow the user to browse through a folder and create a link to the attachment in MS Access? This will solve the size problem I am facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Application.FileDialog:

```
Sub ShowFileDialog()
    Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
    Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    With dlgOpen
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        ''Start in
        .InitialFileName = "Z:\docs\"
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213120(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: +1 You can capture the full filepath with this method and then store it in a table text field

Comment: I am just wondering how do i go about doing this is it in button onclick event. I tried that but had error saying user defined type not defined (compile error). And how do i capture and store it?

Comment: Which version of Access are you using? I have made a small change, does that help?

Comment: ok it worked now thanks, wondering whether there is a way to create a initial path (create a folder too based on my primary key), so when user opens the dialog it goes to the folder.

Comment: Under With dlgOpen `.InitialFileName = "Z:\docs\"` You can find out a lot of the things with Intellisense, Object Browser and F1.

Comment: thanks, so is there a way to create a new folder with name being the primary key.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create a new folder. It is a completely different question. Try a google search, you will find any number of answers.

Comment: Is there a way to get only file name excluding the path, once the user browses to it?